# Why does SQL command containing TABLE and VIEW take long?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

There's a table `T` with columns `T_INDEX` (*unique*), `T_LENGTH` and a view `V` with columns `T_INDEX` (*non-unique*), `V_LENGTH`. They are linked by `T_INDEX`. The following command looks for elements of specific length:

```
[1] select T_INDEX
[2] from T where
[3] (T_LENGTH>=0 and T_LENGTH<=10)
[4] or
[5] T_INDEX in (select T_INDEX from V where V_LENGTH>=0 and V_LENGTH<=10)
```

It is fast (<1 second) if condition on line `[3]` and condition on line `[5]` have at least one matching element. However, it takes long (>2 minutes) if the two conditions have no matching element.

What is the reason for this difference in running time? How can this be avoided?

Comment: Instead of IN, try a JOIN.

Comment: Use JOIN instead IN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance is bad because of your subquery, try this :

```
SELECT_INDEX
FROM T 
LEFT JOIN V ON V.T_INDEX = T.T_INDEX
WHERE
(T_LENGTH>=0 and T_LENGTH<=10 AND V.T_INDEX IS NULL)
OR
(V_LENGTH>=0 and V_LENGTH<=10 AND V.T_INDEX IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: `SELECT T_INDEX` is extended to `SELECT DISTINCT(T_INDEX)` in order to get unique results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 select T_INDEX
 from T left outer join V on T.T_INDEX =  V.T_INDEX and V_LENGTH>=0 and V_LENGTH<=10 where
 (T_LENGTH>=0 and T_LENGTH<=10)
```